# drop down values are not getting accessable from jsp to servlet

Tags: jsp, servlets

```
PrintWriter out=response.getWriter();       
String[] Catg1=request.getParameterValues("Category");
out.println("Category : "+Catg1);
```

catg1 contains null can any one help why it is going to null.

Comment: How do you send parameters to your jsp page?

Comment: add your jsp page so it might be helpful to resolve your problem..@Rushikesh

Comment: add your jsp page so that it would become easy where are you going wrong..

Answer (score 0):

Try this :

```html
<body>
  <h3>Upload Document</h3> 
  Select Category: 
 
     <form action="UploadServlet" method="post">
<select name="rushi" multiple="multiple"> 
  <option value="">Select Category</option>
  <option value="Cat1">Cat1</option> 
  <option value="Cat2">Cat2</option> 
  <option value="other">other</option> 

 
</select>
       </form>
</body> –
```

Answer (score -1):

Check like this...

```
for(int i=0;i<catg1.length;i++)
       {
           pw.println("<li>"+catg1[i]+"</li>");
       }
```

Comment: if it is helpful..dont forget to upvote..@RushikeshMunde

Comment: actually string array contains null values when debug it...<body>
 <h3>Upload Document</h3>
 Select Category:
 <%-- <form action="UploadServlet"method="post"> </form>--%>
 <select name="rushi" multiple="multiple">
  <option value="">Select Category</option>
  <option value="Cat1">Cat1</option>
  <option value="Cat2">Cat2</option>
  <option value="other">other</option>

 </select>

</body>

Comment: String[] Catg1=request.getParameterValues("rushi").use this;